# Is posting of a job offer allowed?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is it allowed to post in TeX.SX a job offer, if I represent a publishing house looking for a professional capable of making books in LaTeX?

Comment: Unfortunately no, [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/job-advertising/6596) and [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/607/) to start with

Comment: ask the various user groups if any of them have a way to post such an offer.  there are also forums such as comp.text.tex or texhax where such a posting wouldn't be rejected.

Comment: Which is not to say that some of us might not be interested ;).

Comment: Which is not to say that other some of us might not be interested ;).